# Regex invalid quantifier for ^((?<!\/)\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]*)+$

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting an invalid quanitifier JS error on this regex.

```
^((?<!\/)\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]*)+$
```

I am simply trying to match any path, and make sure it has a leading slash...

/home
/home/about/
/home/contact
...etc...

Comment: could you not k=just use `/\/[\/\w]*/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `(?<!...)`: JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

I don't think you need it there anyway.

```
^(\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)+\/?$
```

should work as well (depending on your exact rules).

Comment: What advantage does `^\/([A-Za-z0-9_/-]*)+$` have over `^\/([A-Za-z0-9_/-]*$`? I think you can combine these quantifiers - `(...*)+` is equal to `(...*)`.

Comment: @pimvdb: True... that was more copy and paste of the original expression. I updated it so it does make more sense...

Comment: He's trying to avoid double-slashes, which is what the look-behind in the original post was there to do.

Comment: @Pointy: I see... I think I've got something working now (which is the same as yours as I just noticed.... :-/)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your regex, I don't seem to be getting any errors, although nothing is matching (no lookbehinds as Felix Kling says).

However I would suggest the following regex instead:

```
^(?:\/[a-z0-9_-]+)+\/?$
```

Comment: It would not match `/` although I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript regexes don't support lookbehind. You don't need it here however:

```
/^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9_]+)+$/
```

should do it.

*edit* — if trailing slashes are OK then:

```
/^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+)+\/?$/
```

Comment: ah OK yes if trailing slashes are OK then it'd need to change.